# Pinging through sockets in PHP without root/admin rights

Tags: php, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, ping

I am trying to create a function that pings a machine with [socket_create(int $domain, int $type, int $protocol).](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php)

The common way to do this is with the SOCK_RAW type – which allows bypassing the OSI transport layer and making your own ICMPv4 packet (protocol nr. 1 - ICMP). Here is an example:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#101012

Now apparently since Server 2008, bypassing the transport layer requires admin rights. (I also read on the internet that on UNIX systems this also requires the root credentials – but it doesn’t concern me as I am running Server 2008.)

But this is confusing because the ping function in cmd on Windows doesn’t require admin rights. How does it work then? **So is it possible to write a ping-function in PHP that doesn’t require admin rights?**

Comment: Please check the comments in the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580484/php-ping-through-sockets-returns-error-under-iis6windows-2003